# Tips for emulating this illustration style?

Tags: illustration, style

I'm trying to create an Android/iOS game and I'd like a few pointers on creating the style.

I'm trying to go for a style like in [Dragon, Fly](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lsgvgames.slideandfly&hl=en). Are there any tips in color schemes, shading, etc that anyone can offer me?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The game appears to be a rip-off of Tiny Wings: http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/tiny-wings/id417817520?mt=8

Both are basically line drawings--probably built using vector illustration software (Adobe Illustrator, Inkscape, Flash, etc.) And then color and texture added in raster editing software (PhotoShop, The Gimp, Pixelmator, Paint.net, etc.)

I'd argue that Tiny Wings style is much more cohesive, consistent and more aesthetically refined compared to the dragon app.

As for tips, well, color theory and software tutorials are really too broad to be able to cover in a SE question. However, I'd look for some illustration tutorials online. Off the top of my head, someone that might fit the style genre well would be Von Glitschka: http://www.vonglitschka.com/ who runs a blog with some nice explanations of his methods: http://drawsigner.com/